# Listen for localfile.html webview event to be triggered in corona sdk

Tags: webview, lua, listener, coronasdk

I'm building a simple app that requires me to use the webview option

```
local physics = require( "physics" )
local composer = require ( "composer" )
Create a composer scene for this module
local scene = composer.newScene()
function scene:create( event )
local sceneLanding = self.view


local soundID = audio.loadSound ("gummy_music.wav")


local webView = native.newWebView( display.contentCenterX, display.contentCenterY, 320, 480 )
webView:request( "page.html", system.ResourceDirectory )
webView:addEventListener( "urlRequest", webListener )
```

The page pulls up and renders fine

I'm trying to figure out how to use the listener function in coronasdk to play a sound when an event occurs in the local html file.

something like this in my page.lua ?

```
local function webListener( event )
audio.play( soundID )
end
```

I'm looking for a way using jquery to hit the webListener to play the audio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add link to your HTML file like

```
<a href="corona://playsound">Play sound</a>
```

and in listener function you need to check following:

```
local function webListener( event )
    if (event.url and event.url == "corona://playsound") then
        audio.play( soundID )
    end
end
```

This should do the trick

Comment: Thanks, but when I click the link it goes to a 404 type page

Comment: Strange, anyway... you can always use <a href="#playsound">Playsound</a> but you will need to do search in event.url string for "playsound" substring